# Prevent rendering the unicode character in django template

Tags: django, postgresql

I am executing a query to a table in my view and I pass the data to the context dictionary:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(constr)
cur = conn.cursor()

sqlstr = "SELECT DISTINCT adm0_name FROM wld_bnd_adm0_gaul_2015 ORDER BY adm0_name;"
cur.execute(sqlstr)
countries = cur.fetchall()
ctx['countries'] = countries
```

Then I want to render the data in my template as following:

```
{% if countries %}
   {% for cntr in countries %}
      <li><a href="#" id= {{ cntr }}>{{ cntr }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The problem is that I get a unicode format like this:

```
[(u'Abyei',), (u'Afghanistan',), (u...
```

I tried to convert my data in the view to JSON as:

```
countries = json.dumps(countries)
```

But actually then when I render the data in the template I get each single character of the JSON string separately.

Comment: Because after calling `json.dumps`, which serialize obj to a JSON formatted str, you'll get a string (ex: '[["Abyei"], ["Afghanistan"]]'); that's why you get single characters in your for loop

Comment: Any reason you are not using django orm and doing raw SQL query for a simple SELECT?

Comment: @Muhammad Tahir Yes. Actually I haven't passed as a  model in my DB this table. The table is in a different database and I directly do a raw SQL query. Perhaps is better if I also pass it as a model in my django db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs [`fetchall`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall) returns a list of tuples, so each of the country name is inside a tuple in the list. You need to flatten the list to get list of countries.

```
countries = cur.fetchall()
countries = [c[0] for c in countries]
ctx['countries'] = countries
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Python2.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps), here's what you would get after calling `json.dumps`:

```
>>> json.dumps([(u'Abyei',), (u'Afghanistan',)])
'[["Abyei"], ["Afghanistan"]]'
```

Since you get a single JSON formatted string serialized from dictionary, when you iterate it, you'll get a character on every iteration. This explains why you get single characters when you render the data.

Your `countries` is already a dictionary thus can be used without serializing; if you want to convert unicode strings, you can do something like:

```
>>> countries = [(u'Abyei',), (u'Afghanistan',)]
>>> [(country.encode('ascii','ignore'), ) for (country, ) in countries]
[('Abyei',), ('Afghanistan',)]
```